# Extjs fieldset - remove line after title when collapsed

Tags: css, extjs

[image: Fieldset - Remove highlighted line on collapse]

I was trying to remove the line after title (highlighted in attachment) when collapse, I am not able to do it.

I tried to use the `border:0`, which removes only the border on expand. Is there a way to remove this?

```
{
    xtype : 'fieldset',
    border : 0,
    title : '<b>Starting point</b>',
    name : 'startingPt',
    items : [{...}]
}
```

I am using extjs 4.2 On FF

Comment: Thanks for editing Kevin. I will correct when posing next time onwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it can't be done through javascript. as the border-width is given important tag in scss file, it is overriding the 0. It has to be done through additional css.

Below snippet FieldSet.scss file

```
{$prefix}fieldset-collapsed {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
        ***border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px !important;***
```

add the below css:

```
.x-fieldset-collapsed{
   border-width:0 !important;
}
```